# Width de elemento com position: absolute (box-sizing: border-box)

Tags: css

Importante: estou usando Twitter Bootstrap, portanto tudo está com `box-sizing: border-box`.

A dificuldade é a seguinte: tenho um elemento com posicionamento absoluto. Eu quero que a largura dele seja igual ao do elemento pai:

```
div.elemento-filho {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Isso **quase** funciona. O meu problema é que o elemento está ficando mais largo do que o pai, porque o `width` incluiu as margens (`margin`) do elemento pai.

```
div.elemento-pai {
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0px 15px;
}
```

No caso, eu gostaria que a largura do elemento filho não considerasse as margens, ou seja, que ficasse medindo **150px** ao invés de **180px**.

Eu não posso fixar o `width` do elemento-filho, pois ele tem que funcionar para pais de larguras diferentes.

Tem como conseguir isso? De que jeito?

Comment: Sem o `position: absolute`, parece já funcionar. Com o `position: absolute`, fica com muito mais que a diferença das margens. http://jsfiddle.net/ypdtY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso é recomendado que utilize o `position:relative` no elemento pai, isso fará com que os elementos filhos utilizem ele como base de calculo.

Exemplo [[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LkY4/)]:

#### HTML

```
<div id="pai">
    <div id="filho">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#pai{
    width: 180px;
    margin: 0px 15px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    height:10px;
}

#filho{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Links que podem ser uteis: 
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp), [maujor](http://www.maujor.com/)

Comment: Não é que resolveu?! Só agora com sua resposta que parei para pensar, e realmente faz sentido. Já fiz isso para ajustar a **posição** de um elemento filho, várias vezes. Porém, não me passou pela cabeça que pudesse afetar a **largura**. Eu sabia que um elemento com `position: absolute` se baseia no primeiro ancestral com `position` definido para determinar seu **posicionamento**... agora aprendi que ele baseia outros atributos além do posicionamento nesse mesmo ancestral.